# What is the best way to combine two uints into a ulong in c#

Tags: c#, bit-shift, uint, ulong

What is the best way to combine two uints into a ulong in c#, setting the high/low uints.

I know bitshifting can do it, but I don't know the syntax, or there maybe other APIs to help like BitConverter, but I don't see a method that does what I want.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
ulong mixed = (ulong)high << 32 | low;
```

The cast is very important. If you omit the cast, considering the fact that `high` is of type `uint` (which is 32 bits), you'll be shifting a 32 bit value 32 bits to the left. Shift operators on 32 bit variables will use shift stuff by `right-hand-side` mod 32. Effectively, *shifting a `uint` 32 bits to the left **is a no-op***. Casting to `ulong` prevents this.

Verifying this fact is easy:

```
uint test = 1u;
Console.WriteLine(test << 32); // prints 1
Console.WriteLine((ulong)test << 32); // prints (ulong)uint.MaxValue + 1
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why is the cast needed?

Comment: If high is just an int, then high<<32 will be all zeros, because you just shifted all of the ones completely out of the variable.  You need it to be a 64-bit integer *before* you start shifting it.

Comment: Aric: "you just shifted all of the ones completely out of the variable" this is not completely true. Read my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
ulong output = (ulong)highUInt << 32 + lowUInt
```

The `<<` and `>>` operators bitshift to the left (higher) and right (lower), respectively. `highUInt << 32` is functionally the same as `highUInt * Math.Pow(2, 32)`, but may be faster and is (IMO) simpler syntax.

Comment: It's wrong. `highInt << 32 == highInt` if `highInt` is a `uint`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert the highInt to a ulong before you bitshift:

```
ulong output = highInt;
output = output << 32;
output += lowInt;
```

Answer (score 1):

Encoding:

```
ulong mixed = (ulong)hi << 32 | lo;
```

Decoding:

```
uint lo = (uint)(mixed & uint.MaxValue);
uint hi = (uint)(mixed >> 32);
```